# Updatepanels not working when filling the CKEditor / Tinymce from the Database

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, tinymce, updatepanel, richtextbox

I am developing website by using ASP.NET and I am using CKEditor as a richtextbox. In there everythings works fine.

I am using this code to achieve it

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" AutoComplete="off" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="6000"></asp:TextBox><br />

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.3/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('txtJobDescription');
        CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
    };
</script>
```

So everythings works fine.When I save the content of the textbox I am using

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txtDescription.Text)
```

to do it.

Probelem is when I read the saved text from DB and assigned it to Ckeditor text box all the updatepanels in that page are not working.(Which are working properly)
To assign it I am using this code.

```
    DataTable dt=new DataTable
    dt = objBLL.Get(); 
    txtName=Text= dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
    txtDescription.Text = dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();
```

If I comment the last statement all the updatepanels are working properly.
I tried this with tinymce also. Probelem is same.
Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: A wild guess - wrap description value into `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`?

Comment: @Andrei Then updatepanels are working. but in the editor it shows "<ol><li>bbbbbb</li></ol>" like this.

Comment: Are the script and the textbox inside the same update panel?

Comment: @Andrei No this description textbox is not inside an updatepanel. I removed decode and encode from the code.But still probelem is the same.

Comment: All right, so this apparently needs more info in the question. Can you please post one of update panels that is not working, just to understand the relation between the ckeditor, the script tag that initializes it and the update panel? Also it would be helpful to understand were (what page event, is it a postback, triggered by updatepanel or not) do you run the code that assigns text to the ckeditor textbox

Comment: @Andrei My texts are stored in the db like this <p>test text</p> , So if this text retrived to my tinymce textbox, then update panels not working. If I remove <p> tags it is working

Comment: You do realize that you have answered a tiny bit of what the question was about? In fact this answer is just a rephrasing of your original question. Please add more details to the problem to let people understand it better

Comment: @Andrei.. I found the answer. Thank you very much for your support. I disabled ValidateRequestMode=disabled for that specific textbox and its worked.

Comment: Oh, good to know. It would be great if you could post a self-answer then, and accept it. That way other people will know how to resolve this problem, if they ever run into it and google your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering to my own question.

You can either set page ValidateRequest=off at the page level. But this will make other textboxes also post HTML content.

So to avoid that use ValidateRequestMode=disabled in specific control.

This will allow only the selected control posting the HTML tags to server.